# Firestore transaction, implementing multiple gets

Tags: transactions, google-cloud-firestore

Anyone know how to implement multiple gets in a Firestore Transaction?

I have an array of Firestore References, of an unknown length, saved in Firestore. Each reference contains {count: number} and I just want to add one to each reference. To do this I am pretty confident I need to use transactions, and the docs say I can use multiple gets, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

I would think I need to get each reference, store the existing counts in an array, add one to each, then save them all back to Firestore. Every time I've tried to implement this I fail. An example of using multiple gets in a Firestore Transaction is probably all I need to get going, but none exist in the docs, or anywhere online as far as I could find.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use **Promise.all** because you need to iterate each firestore reference of the *arrayOfReferences*.

I made a example for you and tested it, just follow the code below:

```
setCount(arrayOfReferences){
  return this.db.runTransaction(t => {
    return Promise.all(arrayOfReferences.map(async (element) => {
      const doc = await t.get(element);
      const new_count = doc.data().count + 1;
      await t.update(element, { count: new_count });
    }));
  });
}
```

To get to know more about how counters work in Firestore, you can read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters).

Comment: I am unable to use async functions in cloud functions. What should I do ? @Mateus Forgiarini da Silva

Comment: what if you want to update the field with an external input/variable?

Comment: C.Banzet, you just have to pass it as an argument to your function.

Answer (score 1):

The Firestore doc doesn't say this, but the answer is hidden in the API reference: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.13.x/Transaction?authuser=0#getAll

You can use `Transaction.getAll()` instead of `Transaction.get()` to get multiple documents.

Comment: Just tried this, I get `[ts] Property 'getAll' does not exist on type 'Transaction'.`

Comment: I could be wrong, but it appears that `getAll` is only available in the NodeJS libraries for Firestore.